# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy via nginx

Tags: performance, nginx, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to increase the performance of my site. I got about ~83 right now accordingly Google Page Speed Insight. While it's not the worst, it's not great either. One of the issues is **caching**, I need to leverage caching and increase the long life of my static assets.

[image]

My site is behind Cloudflare. Do I need to apply any settings there?

Answer (score 2):

add these lines to : **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|mp3|wav|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff2|woff)$ {
    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

and `service nginx reload`

## Result

[image]